# error in your SQL syntax near (?,?,?)

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I surf the net and don't search what I need. So please you help me.
When I try to execute this SQL statement in Eclipse

```
private final String INSERT_ = "INSERT INTO department VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

I have next error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?)' at line 1
This is my code

```
public void insert(int id, String name, String description) throws SQLException
{
    Department result = null;
    Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_);
    stmt.setInt(1, id);
    stmt.setString(2, name);
    stmt.setString(3, description);
    stmt.executeUpdate(INSERT_);
    System.out.println("Record is inserted into table!");
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I surf the net and don't search what I need.` yes, I've noticed that a lot here on SO.

Answer (score 14):

You shouldn't pass the SQL String to `executeUpdate`, since your `PreparedStatement` was already initialized with the SQL String + the parameters.

Change

```
stmt.executeUpdate(INSERT_);
```

to

```
stmt.executeUpdate();
```